# How to get dynamic value from html tag with foreach and save it to jquery variable for momentObj

Tags: php, jquery, countdowntimer

Honestly i am not sure how to make a suitable title for this but basically i was trying to extract element from `span` tag with `id=duration` which comes dynamically from database with foreach, and use it to display timer for a duration with countdown.js, but i am confused as it is only extracting the first foreach value and not the rest beacause it has the same id i think.
this is the view

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach($status as $row): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php   echo $row->room_name;                         
                                ?></td>
                                <td>                            
                                    <?php if($row->user_name!=null)
                                        {
                                            echo $row->user_name;
                                            
                                        }else{ echo "Available"; }; 
                                    ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php if($row->start_time!=null)
                                        {
                                            echo $row->start_time;
                                        }else{  echo "Available";}; 
                                    ?>
                                </td>
                                <td><span class="timer"><span id="duration"><?php if($row->start_time!=null)
                                        {
                                            echo $row->start_time;
                                        }else{  echo "Available";}; 
                                    ?></span></span></td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php if($row->status!=null)
                                        {
                                            echo $row->status;
                                        }else{ echo "Available";}; 
                                    ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
<script src="assets/home/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/countdown.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dynamic-marquee@1"></script>
<script>
var times = $('#duration').text();
    function update() {
        
        var addDay = /*$('#duration')*/ moment(times);
        $('#clock').html(moment().format('H:mm:ss')+ ' WIB');
        $('.timer').html(addDay.countdown().toString());
        console.log(addDay);
        console.log(times);
    }
    
    setInterval(update, 1000);

    $(window).on("load resize ", function() {
        var scrollWidth = $('.tbl-content').width() - $('.tbl-content table').width();
        $('.tbl-header').css({'padding-right':scrollWidth});
    }).resize();
</script>
<script>
    (function(){var countdown,moment,ref,ref1,slice=[].slice;countdown=(ref=typeof require==="function"?require("countdown"):void 0)!=null?ref:this.countdown;moment=(ref1=typeof require==="function"?require("moment"):void 0)!=null?ref1:this.moment;moment.fn.countdown=function(){var args,other;other=arguments[0],args=2<=arguments.length?slice.call(arguments,1):[];return countdown.apply(null,[this.toDate(),moment(other).toDate()].concat(slice.call(args)))}}).call(this);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since IDs must be unique only use a common class name. In addition you need to change each instance which for this case you can use `text(function)` which internally will loop over each instance.

Then you also want to start the initial `start_time` which you can do using a `data-` attribute. Now whenever you call `update()` you can get the initial value from that attribute and do calculations based on it.

Rather than manufacture some dates/times I created a very simple case that just adds one when called

```js
function update(){
   console.log('Update called')
   $('.timer').text(function(){
       const start = $(this).data('start');
       // do calculations based on start value
       let newVal = start + 1;
       return newVal
   });
}

// only calling it once for simplicity
setTimeout(update, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Room</th>
      <th>Start</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Room 1</td>
      <td>
        <span class="timer" data-start="1">1</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Room 2</td>
      <td>
        <span class="timer" data-start="2">2</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```